How to figure out whether approximations of square roots are convergent to the true value
I am aware that we can approximate irrational roots with infinite continued fractions. Also, I know that we can approximate them with finite continued fractions, and the more coefficients I include in them, the more accurate they will be.
However, I found a way online to represent irrational numbers with something that resembles infinite continued fractions in this link, and i am curious to how should I check whether the approximations converge to the value of $\sqrt{10}$  the more recursions I do.
This way, I can make good approximations.
I have no idea on how to that, and I have checked whether one approximation(putting the same amount of terms) of the corresponding continued fraction of $\sqrt{10}$ would be equal to the same approximation of the fraction created in the blog (who has no mathematical name, i think), to try to prove an equality between this sort of fraction and the continued kind, and it was not, i do not think this is helpful but i put it here just in case.
Edit: Since it was asked, in the link the identity $\sqrt{x}$=1+$\frac{x-1}{1+\sqrt{x}}$ is used, and then recursively we get a infinite continued fraction but with 9's in the numerators and 2's in the coefficients, because, as an example, I have picked x=10.
The nth-approximation is to stop the recursion after n iterations and get a finite fraction  with, as in the infinite case, 9's as numerators and 2's as coefficients.
The link of the website is this:
http://benpaulthurstonblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/estimating-square-roots.html

Infinite (simple) continued fractions do not approximate the root, the give the root exactly. The finite beginnings of the infinite continued fraction expansion of a real number give approximations which converge to the root. It is really unclear what you are asking. Infinite continued fractions are not for "roots," they work for numbers like $\pi$ and $e$ too. Do you mean we can find the infinite continued fraction for the real root of any polynomial?

I'm not following a link. But the link has "square roots" in the text. The word "root" doesn't only refer to square roots. If you are referring to square roots, then adjust your question to make that clear.

If you don't tell us your way of creating a continued fraction, we can't help you know if it works or not.

@ThomasAndrews yes i meant that i can find it for a root, i know that i can use it for transcendental numbers but i am only interested in roots.

@ThomasAndrews i now have told the way, i hope it was clear.

@ThomasAndrews yes i was referring to square roots, sorry.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Have you tried calculating the first few approximations to $\sqrt{10}$, and the first few continued fraction approximations to $\sqrt{10}$, to see how they compare?

@GerryMyerson I have done that. The approximations of the continued fractions behave as expected, and i have been able to find a pattern in the ones i described here, but i do not know how to go from here and prove the pattern continues beside the approximations i made.

Anything of the form $$a_0+{b_1\over a_1+{b_2\over a_2+\dotsb}}$$ is a continued fraction. If $b_j=1$ for all $j$, then we call it a simple continued fraction, and since these are the most studied type we often drop the word "simple" and take it as assumed. But the more general type has also been subjected to much study, and you should be able to find information about its convergence properties by searching the web, or finding a copy of Borwein et al., Neverending Fractions, or Hensley, Continued Fractions, or (continued)

(continued) Jones and Thron, Continued Fractions: Analytic Theory and Applications, or, if your German is up to scratch, Perron, Kettenbrüchen.
